# hide() in Jquery . [Reduce Line ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

```
function hello(this){
 $("#fgCode_span").hide();
    $("#sfgCode_span").hide();
    $("#plant_span").hide();
    $("#fgCode_span2").hide();
    $("#sfgCode_span2").hide();
    $("#plant_span2").hide();
}
```

Its working perfectly fine , but I need to reduce line, instead of writing .Hide() many time for every controls/tags/ids

Please Help. to make it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### jQuery multiple elements Selector

```
$('element1,element2,element3,...');
```

> **Note**: Seperate each element with a comma.

---

### Extended usage

If you will use these in multiple functions, you can try this.

```
const elements = ['#element1', '#element2', '#element3'];

const hide = () => $(elements.join(',')).hide();
const show = () => $(elements.join(',')).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all into a single selector string.

```
function hello() {
    $("#fgCode_span, #sfgCode_span, #plant_span, #fgCode_span2, #sfgCode_span2, #plant_span2").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way I followed to do it

```
$("#fgCode_span ,#sfgCode_span ,#plant_span").hide();
$("#fgCode_span2 ,#sfgCode_span2 ,#plant_span2").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hello(this){
$("#fgCode_span,#sfgCode_span,#plant_span,#fgCode_span2,#sfgCode_span2,#plant_span2").hide();
```

}

```
<div id="fgCode_span">fgCode_span</div>
<div id="sfgCode_span">sfgCode_span</div>
<div id="plant_span">plant_span</div>
<div id="fgCode_span2">fgCode_span2</div>
<div id="sfgCode_span2">sfgCode_span2</div>
<div id="plant_span2">plant_span2</div>
<button onclick="hello(this)">Click To Hide</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).